# How loud are tubular bells?

Tags: percussion, choir, balance

I would like to score a climactic moment in a piece as follows....  a 40 person chorus, (assume a professional adult group) will be singing fortissimo clusters.  Can I expect two notes struck simultaneously on standard orchestra tubular bells to be prominently heard?

Comment: You _could_ specify the type of mallet on the sheet music. Some tubular bell mallets have heads made from hard rolled-up leather, others heads are hard plastic. Leather-headed mallets produce a slightly softer attack than hard mallet heads. But best plan would be mark the part _fortissimo_ and leave the percussionist to get on with it.

Comment: Any other instruments playing at the moment?

Comment: @AndyBonner probably a single cello and bass, but down in their low range so it wouldn't compete.

Comment: Whether or not one sound drowns out another is not only about loudness, but also about in hwat respects they differ. Sustained notes of the human voice are *very* different from a metallic percussion sound; the  bells should have no problem whatsoever.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS Percussionists normally know better than composers which mallet is needed in a specific situation.

Comment: @PiedPiper yes I would usually defer to the percussionist on mallet choice

Comment: @PiedPiper in my experience, classical percussionists tend to err on the side of too soft mallets. Not sure whether this is because it sounds "harder" to the player than the audience due to proximity, or because they want to avoid standing out too much in the ensemble sound. Some conductors may request they choose a harder one, but if you want to ensure a hard sound then it certainly makes sense to make that explicit in the score.

Comment: @leftaroundabout But that's *conductors* making the choice rather than the composer.

Comment: @PiedPiper ...or not. The point is, if you write "hard" in the score, you can be pretty sure it'll be implemented. If you don't, then _maybe_ the player or conductor decides upon it anyway, but they could also assume the __*ff*__ only means the bells are supposed to blend into the volume of the chorus, and then they won't be "prominently heard".

Comment: OT: I once played some during a concert, and hit them so hard that the mallet head broke off and flew across the stage.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tubular bells can be very loud. They can cut through a full orchestra, so what you are proposing should work.

For an example of this kind of writing you might want to listen to a recording of Leonard Bernstein's "Missa brevis" (for chorus and percussion) which uses bells prominently.

(particularly at 2:37)